# Angular 9 why the values ​in the view do not change

Tags: typescript, view, onchange, angular9, webapi

I use the WebSensorApi a lot and would like to have the sensor values ​​displayed in my view.
In a past project, the values ​​were shown without any problem. Now I have used the exact same code in another project and the view changes strangely only when a click event is triggered. which has nothing to do with it at all.

why is that?

Comment: Hey there, for others to help, you need post some code snippets to review.

Answer (score 0):

A code snippet about my problem.

the problem is that the view is not updated with the sensor data ..

**component.ts**

```
.
.
.
count;
permission: Boolean = true;

ngOnInit() {
    this.getAcceleration();
  }



getAcceleration() {
    if (this.isPermission) {
     (DeviceMotionEvent as any).requestPermission()
      .then(permissionState => {
      if (permissionState === 'granted') {
       window.addEventListener('devicemotion', (data) => {
        this.count = data.acceleration.x;
       });
      }
     })
      .catch(console.error);
    } else {

    }
   }

.
.
.
```

**component.html**

```
<h1>Show Acceleration data</h1>

<p>{{count}}</p>
```